# Why is installing Office 2013 with Click-to-Run so Slow?

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-8.1

After my previous Office installation went bad, I have been forced to reinstall it. The installation process is taking forever. Why is this the case, even though my internet is relatively fast. Could this be because Microsoft's servers are being hammered at the moment?

[image]

Comment: Microsoft's servers can handle thousands of customers.  The problem is your bandwidth.

Comment: @Ramhound The screenshot posted above was posted about an hour ago, and the bar has only grown a little since then. Should I just leave this running all night and wake up ready to install Office? I have a hard time believing that my connection is that bad when I can load a website with lightning speed. Could something on my computer be slowing me down.

Comment: I don't really know.  All I know is that hundreds of people download office without a problem daily.

Comment: Click 2 Run uses a Streaming Technology (App-V) and depending on your bandwidth it may take some time to download all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure why it was so slow at first, but a few minutes ago, the progress bar went from creeping across the screen, and flew to the end. Despite the fact that I do not understand what was going on, the issue seems to be resolved now.